# WCF Service only works for the first call

Tags: wcf

We are developing a WCF Service that's called from a windows client.
The first time the Client calls the service we get a response but the second call times out.
Once we recycle the application pool or restart the service it works for another call.
It almost looks like the service dies but we are logging all exceptions on the server and there are no indications that the service errors out...

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: any code you can post, what does the method do or look like that you're calling on the WCF service

Comment: What does this have to do with asp-classic?

Comment: Check the Windows Event Log, any unhandled exceptions that cause the whole process to crash should be logged there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies...
We found and fixed the problem: 
we are using a thread method to post notifications form the web service to another web service. Since we experienced performance problems when running the service we limited the ThreadPool.MaxThreads, after removing that limitation the service works as expected.